# Запуск backend и frontend на nodejs

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

Решил запустить небольшое nodejs/vuejs приложение форума из этого репозитория: https://github.com/marcelobbfonseca/forum

После всех манипуляций (npm install / правка конфиг файла) пытаюсь запустить приложение. Если запускать из корневой директории (npm run dev) запускается бэкенд на localhost:3000. Если запускать из поддиректории frontend (npm run serve) запускается фронтенд на localhost:8080. Полагаю, что это не совсем правильный способ запуска подобных приложений, поскольку в самом репозитории все запросы из фронтенда в бэкенд идут относительными путями (/api/v1/settings, например). Иными словами, как правильно нужно запускать подобные приложения на nodejs, чтобы фронт и бек работали на одном хосте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно в начале собрать фронтенд: `cd frontend && npm install && npm run build`

Затем нужно запустить бек: в корне проекта(не `frontend`, а всего проекта) нужно запустить сервер через `node server.js`

Сервер будет запущен на порту из конфига (3000, если не указан).

Теперь о том как это работает. После запуска `npm run build` фронт собирается в статику - `frontend/dist`. После запуска сервера он будет перенаправлять все запросы на фронт (кроме серверных вида `/api/***`), за это отвечает строка  в `server.js`:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'frontend', 'dist', 'index.html'))
})
```